# Register Form auto close

Tags: javascript, php

When I click my submit button inside the form , it will close automatically and I need to click again for the button to open the form again.

How can I make the form didn't close after submit and can show error message inside the form?

```
<html>
<?php include 'demo4.php';
  include 'login.php'?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font- awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/forum-style.css" />

<body>
<div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; font-size: 14px;color:#666;text-align:left">
    <header class="popupHeader">
        <span class="header_title">Register</span>
    </header>
    <section class="popupBody">
        <div class="">
        <div class="user_register">
            <form action ='' method='POST' id="register_form">
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" name = 'fullname'/>
                <label style="color:red"><?php echo $lengthErr;?></label>
                <br/>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name = 'uname' />
                <label style="color:red"><?php echo $unameErr; echo $unamelErr; echo $lengthErr;?></label>
                <br/>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="pass"/>
                <label style="color:red"><?php echo $lengthpErr; echo $passErr;?></label>
                <br/>
                <label>Repeat Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="r_pass"/>
                <label style="color:red"><?php echo $passErr;?></label>
                <br />

                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="useremail"/>
                <br />

                <label>Gender &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="gender">
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
                </label>
                <br />
                <label style="color:red"><?php echo $fillErr;?></label>
                <div class="action_btns">
                    <input type ='submit' name='register' value="Register" class="btn btn_red">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>

        </section>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 150, overlay : 0.7});

$("#register_form").click(function() {
         $(".user_register").show();
</script>
```

Comment: There are two options: have your server-side post handler re-render the form and include post-back data... Or, the better option is to use Javascript to intercept the form submit and send it as an ajax request.

Comment: When you submit your form your form submitted on same page as you didn't pass action value in form and page get reload. If you want to show your form all the time you can set your `modal` style to `display:block;`

Comment: simple you have to toggle again if any error.